# $\zeta$ function for ambiguous class group

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $K$ be a Galoisian number field with ring of integers $O_K$. I consider $\zeta_{A,K}(s)$ the function defined by
$$\zeta_{A,K}(s)=\prod_{\substack{p\in\mathbb N\\p\text{ prime}}}\dfrac1{1-\mathrm{Norm}(\prod_{\substack{\mathfrak P\in\mathrm{Spec}(O_K)\\\mathfrak P\mid p}}\mathfrak P)^{-s}}$$
My $\zeta_{A,K}$ would be an analog for the ambigous class group of $O_K$ of the $\zeta_K$ function for the class group.

Has my $\zeta_{A,K}$ function already been introduced and studied. If yes, cann you provide some references.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems to me this is just the Riemann zeta function at $[K:\mathbb{Q}]s$ with finitely many factors modified, no ?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know the notation $[K:\mathbb Q]_s$. Can you expand your comment?

Comment: Chris means the complex variable $s$ in $\zeta(s)$ is replaced by the product $[K:\mathbf Q]s$.

Comment: So, there is no hope that the cardinality of the ambiguous class group is related to special values of this $\zeta$ function....